# Django clickable field for href

Tags: django, model, field

i am working on a project in django where i have a model called Result with a read field and i want that this field will also use for link reference .
my model:

```
class Results(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField()
    read= models.CharField(choices=RELEVANCE_CHOICES,max_length=20,default="Unread")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to understand your question, but I'm guessing that, rather than use choices you want a related model, like so:

```
class ReadStatus(models.Model):
    status=models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Result(models.Model):
    read_status=models.ForeignKey(
             ReadStatus, null=False,
             default=lambda: ReadStatus.objects.get(status="Unread"))
    creation_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
```

A few notes:

1. Each instance of the model (Result) for example, references a single row - hence my use of the singular "Result" rather than Results (obviously, you can do whatever you want, but understanding the reasoning sometimes helps.)
2. The default is set using a query - which ASSUMES that there is a single row in ReadStatus that has status of "Unread". If that's not the case, then you will have issues using the default for the Result model.